# How does browser select a css property value to render from two different css selectors rules?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm working on a Bootstrap project, the first task is to use Bootstrap navbar to build a navigation in the header. I want to use collapse functionality of Bootstrap to create a dropdown-menu div, when users hover or active a nav item, it will be visible. I want to make this dropdown-menu div 100% width of the screen.
Here's the sample code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a ...>ABOUT</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The question is: the position property of dropdown-menu is absolute, which makes this div positioned based on the closest positioned ancestor. In the sample code is "li" tag, because in Bootstrap there's a rule:

```
.nav>li{
  position: relative;
}
```

When I add a rule, which could make this "li" tag position static:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  position: inherit;
}
```

This rule is ignored by browser, I found this from Chrome inspect. When I uncheck the nav>li rule, my rule works. I want to know how does browser choose which of the css property value to render when it gets two rules on the same element and same property?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, specificity. The more specific the selector is, the higher priority it will be given.

For more details, look here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Having said that, your rule appears to be wrong, as you need a dot to indicate a class...

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your link, that's what I want, let me modify my question first.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. The link contains loads of good examples as well.